# Class object being initialized outside the method is not recognized

Tags: object, interface

I already found the issue and moved the class object inside one of the methods, so I guess I'm just kind of curious why an object such as this `MyObject name = new MyObject();` is not recognized but this `private static int intName` works when initialized (declared) on top of the methods right after "class Program" or whatever your class is.

Answer (score 1):

both should work. If you are accessing it from a static method you need to add static keyword to the object definition like below.

```
private static MyObject name = new MyObject();
```

if you are accessing the same from instance method

```
MyObject name = new MyObject();
```

is fine. I am assuming this was your problem

Comment: oh ok, but my object is not static it's an abstract/interface combo

Comment: static is different from abstract/interface. static keyword just associates a variable/method to a class